# Babel src block inside src block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to post a babel src block that contains a babel definition since I am documenting some babel source blocks in a Hugo post written in org mode.

What I want to do is the following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file my_output_file.png :cmdline -Kdot -Tpng
digraph G {
  my_start -> one_branch;
  my_start -> another_branch;
}
#+END_SRC
#+END_SRC
```

And the output I'd like to achieve when exporting is:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file my_output_file.png :cmdline -Kdot -Tpng
digraph G {
  my_start -> one_branch;
  my_start -> another_branch;
}
#+END_SRC
```

BUt what I get instead is

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file my_output_file.png :cmdline -Kdot -Tpng
digraph G {
  my_start -> one_branch;
  my_start -> another_branch;
}
```

Since the first #+END_SRC finishes the code block.

Is there any way to escape the #+END_SRC so I can have my src block as I expect?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You escape the inside `#+BEGIN` and `#+END` by prefixing them with a `,`. You can find many such examples [here in my `ox-hugo` test file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo/master/test/site/content-org/all-posts.org).. just search for `,#`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can include any orgmode inside a literal example (SRC or EXAMPLE blocks, or even headings).

You may need to escape headings and block delimiters with a comma. This escaping is done automatically if you edit your block in a separate buffer via `C-c '`.

Documentation [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html#fnd-4).

Example of block with escaped heading and source block:

```
* Test

#+begin_src org
  ,* this is a heading

  The following is a source code example

  ,#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (+ 1 2 3 4)
  ,#+end_src

  ,#+RESULTS:
  : 10
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the outer block to be a SRC block? The standard way I think of doing what you want is like this:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
#+BEGIN_SRC dot ...
...
#+END_SRC
#+END_EXAMPLE
```