# use org-mode babel execution to generate templates for org-mode execution

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

**Background**

I want to use org-mode to create a WBS to then create JIRA issues.

org-babel looks like the right option as I can use shell to invoke curl commands to invoke the JIRA API for create issues.

So this is a multi-step process:

- write the WBS as a normal org-mode hierarchy
- use org-babel to process the tree and generate the curl commands
- use org-babel to invoke the curl commands

**Problem**

My problem, I can't find any documentation that tells me how to do this in two passes, that is being able to manually invoke the results of one org-block.

It's not really [source code blocks ability to pass variables, functions, and results to one another](https://orgmode.org/manual/Features.html#Features)

Section [15.6 Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation) doesn't show which magic incantation of collection, type, format is needed either.

The [Worg's The Library of Babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/library-of-babel.html) or [Worg's Babel: Introduction](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html) didn't have any examples.

It's almost [Babel src block inside src block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35489/babel-src-block-inside-src-block) which was useful for the links on escaping org-mode special syntax, and the link to [12.6 Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html#fnd-4)

Answer (score 3):

Which [15.6 Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation) options are needed?

**Collection**: `value`

Why? Because `output` puts it into scripting mode and you need to write to the standard output stream for the results.

My initial problems with `value` was that I was trying to return an elisp list as the result of the function, and org-mode was pretty printing the list onto a single line needing me to find [How do I prevent extremely long lines making Emacs slow?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-prevent-extremely-long-lines-making-emacs-slow)

I was relying on org determining the correct type and format for me, which may have contributed to misunderstandings.

**Type**: unspecified

Manually setting this to each of the values: ‘table’, ‘vector’, ‘list’, ‘scalar’, ‘verbatim’ produced incorrect results.

**Format**: `org` with `wrap: SRC shell`

The output is a list of shell commands, so it needs to be wrapped in a `#+begin_src` block. The wrap header changes this from the default `#+begin_org` to `#+begin_src` and appends `shell` to the wrapped block.

**Results of Function**: multi-line string

This bit caused a lot of problems.

I assumed I could build up my list structure and org-mode would do the right thing. Having the long lines issue making Emacs slow also didn't help trial-and-error coding.

**Example code**

Please excuse my poor Emacs-fu. This code works, I have no idea whether it conforms to anything remotely like decent elisp style.

```
#+NAME: generate-jira-create-issue-commands
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value org :wrap SRC shell
  (require 's)
  (let* ((base-url "https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2")
         (resource-name "issue")
         (defaults '(("projectId" . 12345) ; your project id in your JIRA instance
                     ("issuetypeId" . 3) ; JIRA "Task"
                     ("assigneeName" . "<your user id>")))
         (commands '())
         (headings '())
         (api-url (s-format "${base-url}/${resource-name}" 'aget `(("base-url" . ,base-url) ("resource-name" . ,resource-name))))
         (jira-create-issue-template "curl --insecure -b ~/jira-session.txt --request POST --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data '{\"fields\": {\"project\": {\"id\": \"${projectId}\"}, \"summary\": \"${summary}\", \"description\": \"${description}\", \"assignee\": {\"name\": \"${assigneeName}\"}, \"issuetype\": {\"id\": \"${issuetypeId}\"}}}' ${api-url}"))
    (org-element-map
        (org-element-parse-buffer)
        'headline
      (lambda (heading)
        (push (org-element-property :raw-value heading) headings)))
    (dolist (heading headings)
      (let* ((template-values `(("api-url" . ,api-url)
                                ("summary" . ,heading)
                                ("description" . ".")
                                ,@defaults))
             (command (s-format jira-create-issue-template 'aget template-values)))
        (push command commands)
        (push (concat "# " heading) commands)))
    (s-join "\n" commands))
#+END_SRC
```

I can then run <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> inside this block to process the entire org buffer and the `RESULTS` will contain all the curl commands I need to run wrapped in `#+begin_SRC shell`.

```
#+RESULTS: generate-jira-create-issue-commands
#+begin_SRC shell
# Heading 1
curl --insecure -b ~/jira-session.txt --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"fields": {"project": {"id": "12345"}, "summary": "Heading 1", "description": ".", "assignee": {"name": "<your user id>"}, "issuetype": {"id": "3"}}}' https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue
...
# Heading N
curl --insecure -b ~/jira-session.txt --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"fields": {"project": {"id": "12345"}, "summary": "Heading N", "description": ".", "assignee": {"name": "<your user id>"}, "issuetype": {"id": "3"}}}' https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue
#+end_SRC
```

I can then run <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> inside the `RESULTS` block to run the curl commands.

Comment: That's amazing.  I agree there should be more examples out there using `:wrap SRC ...`